# Nginx not routing to index.html by default on AKS

Tags: vue.js, nginx, azure-aks

I've deployed my Vue application to AKS using nginx as a web server. Now I have a couple of routes defined in my Vue application, but when I navigate to any route not being defined it shows me a default 404 page from nginx. I've set up my nginx configuration like this:

## nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;

worker_processes  1;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

# possible levels are: debug | info | notice | warn | error | crit
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

And then some server configuration like this:

## site.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index  index.html;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Now I've seen some examples where the location is set as how I've done it, but still it doesn't seem to work/reflect. I've also tried redeploying a couple of times, but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

root   /usr/share/nginx/html; make sure files right place

root   /usr/share/nginx/html; move to outside brackets under server_name

try running site.conf inside nginx.conf then restart